# $1 + \frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{3} +..... +\frac {1}{p-1} = \frac {a}{b}$, prove that $a$ is divisible by $p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

If $p$ is an odd prime and if $1 + \frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{3} +..... +\frac {1}{p-1} = \frac {a}{b}$, where, $a,b$ are positive integers, prove that $a$ is divisible by $p$.

I found this exercise in a book of ring theory. How can I use rings to prove the above??

Comment: Your sum mod $p$ is a rearrangement of $1+2+\cdots+(p-1)$.

Comment: $a$ is divisible by $p^2$ too. See [Wolstenholme's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

I'm really just repeating what is in the comments. Multiply $\frac{a}{b}$ by a number $k$ that is not a multiple of $p$ but is a multiple of $1,2,3\dots p-1$. Then you have $\frac{ak}{b}$ is $k+\frac{k}{2}+\frac{k}{3}\dots \frac{k}{p-1}$. Since inverses are unique and $\frac{k}{2}\equiv k\cdot 2^{-1}$ what you  have is indeed a rearrangement of all the congruence classes $\bmod p$. So $\frac{k}{1}+\frac{k}{2}+\dots \frac{k}{p-1}\equiv 1+2+3+\dots +(p-1)=\frac{p(p-1)}{2}\equiv 0 \bmod p$.

Therefore $ka$ is a multiple of $p$, and by euclid's lemma $a$ is a multiple of $p$.

Comment: that's using number theory.....but how i will do it using ring theory??

Comment: if you know ring theory whacka's argument alone should be enough.